# Matching a Repeating Pattern After Specific String

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a repeated pattern (of ip mumbers) but only after a specific string has occured. I could do this first by split and running regex on the second part but I am wondering if I can do this with a single regex. Example is

```
import re

s4 = """
ddddddhhhhhhf jjjjjj 111.222.33.444 dddddd ddddddddddd
ccccccccccc
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxj kkkkkk kkkkkk xxxxx111.222.888.444yyyy
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxj kkkkkk kkkkkk xxxxx111.555.888.444yyyy
dddddd jjjjjjj 333.222.33.444 111.222.33.444 jjjjjjjjjjjj
"""
```

I would like to match all ip numbers after ccccc. If I do

```
regex = "cccccc.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)+"
res = re.findall(regex, s4, re.DOTALL)
```

I only get 111.222.888.444. If I used

```
regex = "(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)+"
```

I would get all ip numbers which is not what I need. Which regex syntax is necessary to make this work?

Thanks,

Comment: Something like https://ideone.com/TZ1dOr can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex based on alternation strategy to match and discard text till first match on LHS and keep matching regex on RHS in capture group:

```
(?s)^.*?c{11}|(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WqwSaG/2)

**Code:**

```
>>> print (filter(None, re.findall(r'^(?s).*?c{11}|(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', s4)))
['111.222.888.444', '111.555.888.444', '333.222.33.444', '111.222.33.444']
```

[Code Demo](https://eval.in/1058440)

`filter` is used to discard an empty match from output.

Comment: Worked well. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `^(?s).*?c{11}|((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)` for sake of being concise?

Comment: Definitely `c{11}` is more concise than `ccccccccccc` (edited)

Comment: what is `(?s)` doing?

Comment: `(?s)` enables `DOTALL` mode to enable dot match newlines as well.